# jcuda cuModuleLoad() cannot load file using the path of getClass().getResource().getPath()

Tags: jcuda

I am trying to use `cuModuleLoad()` in JCuda to load a `vectorAdd.ptx` file from `/src/main/resources`. The code is as follows:

```
cuModuleLoad(module, getClass.getResource("vectorAdd.ptx").getPath())
```

But the `cuModuleLoad()` doesn't pick up this file. It only works when I pass in the absolute path of the `ptx file`. But I would like to have the `ptx file` shipped with compile `jar files`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`cuModuleLoad` function in JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/JCudaDriver.html#cuModuleLoad%28jcuda.driver.CUmodule,%20java.lang.String%29) is a direct mapping to the corresponding [`cuModuleLoad` function in CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE_1g366093bd269dafd0af21f1c7d18115d3). It expects a file name as the second argument.

The problem is: `cuModuleLoad` can not load the PTX file, because the PTX file simply does not exist for CUDA! The PTX file is hidden inside the JAR file.

---

When you obtain a resource from a JAR file using `someClass.getResource()`, then it will point to the resource in the JAR file. When you do something like

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("vectorAdd.ptx").getPath());
```

and run this (as a JAR file), then you will see an output like this:

```
file:/U:/YourWorkspace/YourJarFile.jar!/vectorAdd.ptx
```

Note the `.jar!` part: This path is **not** a path to a real file, but only a path to a *resource in the JAR*.

---

In order to load the PTX file from a JAR, you have to read the PTX file from the JAR into a `byte[]` array on Java side, and then pass it to the [`cuModuleLoadData` function of JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/JCudaDriver.html#cuModuleLoadData%28jcuda.driver.CUmodule,%20byte[]%29) (which corresponds to the [`cuModuleLoadData` function of CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html#group__CUDA__MODULE_1g04ce266ce03720f479eab76136b90c0b)).

Here is an example that loads the PTX data from a JAR file into a byte array, representing the zero-terminated string that can be passed to `cuModuleLoadData`:

```
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.cuCtxCreate;
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.cuDeviceGet;
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.cuInit;
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.cuModuleGetFunction;
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.cuModuleLoadData;
import static jcuda.runtime.JCuda.cudaDeviceReset;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import jcuda.driver.CUcontext;
import jcuda.driver.CUdevice;
import jcuda.driver.CUfunction;
import jcuda.driver.CUmodule;
import jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver;

public class JCudaPtxInJar
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        // Initialization
        JCudaDriver.setExceptionsEnabled(true);
        cuInit(0);
        CUdevice device = new CUdevice();
        cuDeviceGet(device, 0);
        CUcontext context = new CUcontext();
        cuCtxCreate(context, 0, device);

        // Read the PTX data into a zero-terminated string byte array
        byte ptxData[] = toZeroTerminatedStringByteArray(
            JCudaPtxInJar.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "JCudaVectorAddKernel.ptx"));

        // Load the module data
        CUmodule module = new CUmodule();
        cuModuleLoadData(module, ptxData);

        // Obtain a function pointer to the "add" function
        // and print a simple test/debug message
        CUfunction function = new CUfunction();
        cuModuleGetFunction(function, module, "add");
        System.out.println("Got function "+function);

        cudaDeviceReset();
    }

    /**
     * Read the contents of the given input stream, and return it
     * as a byte array containing the ZERO-TERMINATED string data 
     * from the stream. The caller is responsible for closing the
     * given stream.
     * 
     * @param inputStream The input stream
     * @return The ZERO-TERMINATED string byte array
     * @throws IOException If an IO error occurs
     */
    private static byte[] toZeroTerminatedStringByteArray(
        InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[8192];
        while (true)
        {
            int read = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        baos.write(0);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Compiling this and packing it into a JAR (together with the `/resources/JCudaVectorAddKernel.ptx` PTX file, of course) will allow you to start the program and obtain the example function from the PTX in the JAR.

Comment: This is an awesome solution! Thank you very much. The only thing that I want to point out is that the path to JCudaVectorAddKernel.ptx passed to getResourceAsStream() should be just "JCudaVectorAddKernel.ptx"

Comment: @Xiangyu That depends on where the file is located in the JAR. But if it is copied into the classes folder, then it can be omitted - I'll update it, although it should not make much difference, conceptually.